# SQLDeveloper sometimes suddenly doesn't open Worksheet on connect

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using **SQLDeveloper** since about > 12 years (currently 20.2) and have to deal with about 70 different databases.
I have activated under **( Properties / Database / Worksheet) "Open a Worksheet on connect"**.

So, usually whenever I open a new session via Connections, a new Worksheet is automatically opened.

Unfortunately sometimes and suddenly it doesn't work anymore and no new Worksheet gets opened on new connect. I have then always to "Open SQL Worksheet" manually, which works.
This happens already since years and many versions and I don't have any clue, why.
Even uncheck and check this property doesn't help.

After restarting, it works again like a charm.

Does anybody have an idea, why and if I can reactivate it without restarting? I don't like restart, to avoid loosing all detailed working results.

Comment: SQL Developer is just another piece of *software*. At least 90% of all problems are "solved" by restarting it (not to mention by restarting MS Windows). Therefore, if what you described isn't a *feature* (Jeff will know), then it might be a *bug*. Maybe it is fixed in the most recent version. As it is free, why wouldn't you upgrade?

Comment: That's clear and I mentioned already, that I don't like to restart as long as I'm not forced to do so just because I hit an annoying bug. That's, why I'm asking, if somebody has a better idea.
And, I've seen this bug since years. Means, I've experienced it also in former releases from time to time.